# Script Copy/Paste with Criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that will copy and paste data from non-consecutive columns and I have a script that will copy and paste data based on multiple criteria however after numerous attempts I have been unable to create a script that does both. Any help would be appreciated. For the following code the error is;

> The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range.

```js
function UpdateTeam() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');          // Source workbook
  var sourcesheet = source.getSheetByName("Test").getDataRange().getValues();                    // *Source workbook sheet, sheets vary by location. Case sensitive.
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                              // Destination workbook
  var destsheet = dest.getSheetByName("Team");                                                   // Destination workbook sheet

  var criteria1 = "Active"                                                                       // Criteria #1
  var criteria2 = "Hop"                                                                          // *Criteria #2, change to location name in

  destsheet.getRange(6, 1, destsheet.getLastRow(), destsheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent()      // Clear all previous content on destination sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();                                                                         // Wait till the clear sheet is complete before adding new

  var sourcerange  = [4,2,1,4,5,7,11,12,4,64,4,65,4,68,69,70,4,75];                               // Columns of data to import
  var newvalues = [];

  for (var i = 0, length = sourcesheet.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (sourcesheet[i][1]==criteria1 && sourcesheet[i][2]==criteria2){
      newvalues[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0, width  = sourcerange.length; j < width; j++) {
    if (sourcesheet[i][1]==criteria1 && sourcesheet[i][2]==criteria2){
        newvalues[i][j] = sourcesheet[i][sourcerange[j]];
      }
    }
  }
  }
    if(newvalues.length > 0) {   
      destsheet.getRange(6, 1, length +1, width +1).setValues(newvalues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function UpdateTeam() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var svA=sss.getSheetByName("Test").getDataRange().getValues();
  var dss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dsh=dss.getSheetByName("Team");
  var criteria1="Active";
  var criteria2="Hop";
  dsh.getRange(6,1,dsh.getLastRow()-5,dsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  var srg=[4,2,1,4,5,7,11,12,4,64,4,65,4,68,69,70,4,75];
  var newvalues = [];
  for (var i=0;i<svA.length;i++) {
    if (svA[i][1]==criteria1 && svA[i][2]==criteria2){
      var row=[];
      srg.forEach(function(e,j){row.push(svA[i][srg[j]]);})
      newvalues.push(row);
    }
  }
  if(newvalues){dsh.getRange(6,1,newvalues.length,srg.length).setValues(newvalues);}
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, just had to change var i=0,i<svA to var i=0**;**i<svA. If possible could you possibly explain how function(e,j) works? Also not sure how srg[j] works either. Regardless, thank you.

Comment: it's an anonymous function in a forEach method. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks again for the help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with newvaluess array length. It does not match with sourcerange array length.

You can check it by adding this code into your code.

```
Browser.msgBox("sourcerange length: " + sourcerange.length + " | newvalues length: " + newvalues.length);
return;
if(newvalues.length > 0) {   
  destsheet.getRange(6, 1, length +1, width +1).setValues(newvalues);
}
```

I think that the problem is that you don`t add else, to add an empty slot in the array, to keep same length when not matching criteria.